# Accidently deleted my /etc/default folder

Tags: boot, filesystem

I Accidently deleted my `/etc/default` folder. Now my computer wont boot.
Its running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. 
Upon boot it says,

```
Filesystem check or mount failed. 
A maintenance shell will now be started.CONTROL-D will terminate this shell and continue booting after re-trying filesystems. Any further errors will be ignored.
```

Please help, this is a very important computer and cannot suffer any downtime.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just boot from Ubuntu live disk and copy the `/etc/default` directory(*live disk*) to the `/etc` directory(*Resides in the partition where Ubuntu is actually installed*)

```
sudo mkdir /media/os
sudo mount /dev/sdaX /media/os   # Mounting the root partition on /media/os directory.
sudo cp -Ri /etc/default /media/os/etc
sudo umount /dev/sdaX
```

Shutdown and boot from your Hard-disk. Hope it will work.