# How to replace /etc/apt folder after deleting it

Tags: 14.04, apt

My `/etc/apt` directory was removed from my installation. How can I rebuild that directory?

My OS is Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: did you try to create a new /etc/apt as root and then run 'sudo apt-get update' ?

Comment: Just copy `/etc/apt` folder from the installation disk.

Comment: @AvinashRaj there is no such folder in installation disk

Comment: @philshem I did it but and problem exists. I'm trying to get this folder from another computer

Comment: copy from another worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If You have `iso` image of Ubuntu, then follow these steps:**

- First mount iso file in `/media/cdrom`

  ```
   sudo mkdir /media/cdrom
   sudo mount -o loop ubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.iso /media/cdrom
  ```

  Where `"ubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.iso"` is filename of your iso file
- Then mount `filesystem.squashfs` at `/mnt`

  ```
  sudo mount -o loop /media/cdrom/casper/filesystem.squashfs /mnt
  ```
- Now you can copy `/etc/apt` from `/mnt/etc/apt`

---

**If You have live disk then follow these steps:**

- Mount `/casper/filesystem.squashfs` from disk to `/mnt`

  ```
  sudo mount -o loop "/media/pandya/Ubuntu 14.04 LTS i386/casper/filesystem.squashfs" /mnt
  ```

  where "pandya" is username and "Ubuntu 14.04 LTS i386" is disk in my case
- Now you can copy `/etc/apt` from `/mnt/etc/apt`

Comment: Yeh, What are you trying to say?

Comment: You can't able to view `/etc/apt` folder in a mounted Ubuntu.iso file.

Comment: is it? You better recommend op to boot from a live disk and then copy `/etc/apt` folder to the partition where Ubuntu is installed.

Comment: @AvinashRaj : I added both (live-disk & iso) method.

Comment: no, it would be like this http://askubuntu.com/a/457607/202806