# How to recover accidentally removed /bin/ls binary

Tags: command-line, package-management, data-recovery, rm

I have mistakenly deleted the `ls` executable from the `/bin` folder.

Can I recover it or install it through the terminal?

Comment: Also available are the "crazytown answers", e.g. "Google the source for the Plan9 ls, type it in, and use gcc to compile it". (In all seriousness, @c0rp has the correct answer when it's just one program you nuked. Try installing `trash-cli` for the future.)

Comment: You can also recover files that comes with Ubuntu from iso or live cd. Visit similar [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/469998/256099)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could check which package brings `ls` binary using `dpkg`:

```
$ dpkg -S /bin/ls
coreutils: /bin/ls
```

`dpkg` will show you that it is package `coreutils`. Now you only need to reinstall it:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall coreutils
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that my answe is coming is too late but it will assist others in the future.
I had deleted `ls` command

As a root user,

Use

```
# sudo apt update
```

Then after the update,

Type your deleted command.
In my case

```
# ls
```

Then you'll see a prompt

```
Command 'ls' not found can be installed with:
apt install coreutils
Do you want to install it? (N/y) then type y
```

You're done wait for it to update! Go back confirm if it is done
As a root user type the deleted command

```
ls
```